# asp.net core with angular 4 and Kendo UI

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I setup Angular 2 app with ASP.NET Core Web Application Visual Studio 2017

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ISXzctm5-D4

and it was working, but I added Kendo UI to my app, and now I get this error.

[image: my application is broken]

Comment: At what stage do you get this error?

Comment: We could do with seeing some code.  How did you add Kendo UI to your app?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue with kendo UI. Apparently the `systemjs.config.js` file was not being updated automatically and I had to add the mapping manually to the kendo Ui packages.

This is how my systemjs.config.js file looks like now:

```js
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': '/node_modules/',
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      'app': 'app',
      'systemjs-json-plugin': 'npm:systemjs-plugin-json',
      '@telerik': 'http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/npm/node_modules/@telerik',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/animations': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations.umd.js',
      '@angular/animations/browser': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser/animations': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

      '@progress/kendo-angular-buttons': 'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-buttons/dist/cdn/js/kendo-angular-buttons.js',
      "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": 'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-l10n/dist/cdn/js/kendo-angular-l10n.js',
      // other libraries
      'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        defaultExtension: 'js',
        meta: {
          './*.js': {
            loader: 'systemjs-angular-loader.js'
          }
        }
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

I hope this works for you as well.

Answer (score -1):

```
1. Add kendo ui on angular 
    npm login --registry=https://registry.npm.telerik.com/ --scope=@progress

2. npm install --save @progress/kendo-angular-buttons @progress/kendo-angular-l10n @angular/animations


3. src/app/app.module.ts
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';


import { ButtonsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-buttons';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,

        // Register the modules
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        ButtonsModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }


4. src/app/app.component.html:
<h1>{{title}}</h1>

<button kendoButton (click)="onButtonClick()" [primary]="true">My Kendo UI Button</button>


5. app.component.ts:

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'Hello World!';

    onButtonClick() {
        this.title = 'Hello from Kendo UI!';
    }`enter code here`
}
```